# Android : How to not overlap dynamic views? + dynamic position of views

Tags: android, dynamic, view, augmented-reality, overlapping

I develop an Augmented Reality application which display markers on a camera view.
The markers are views dynamically created by getting positions in a database. A marker represents a building for example, described by a name and a position (latitude / longitude).

When the application is launched, I get the current location of the phone and display the markers on the screen according to their locations and the orientation of the phone (SensorManager).

The problem is that when markers are in the same direction, they are overlapped. I would like that the markers are arranged one over one.

I tried using a RelativeLayout but it doesn't change anything.

Code for markers Creation :

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();


        for(int j=0;j<markers.length;j++) {
            //System.out.println(prefMarkers[j]);
            if(markers[j] == null) {

                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

                    markers = new DataList(); // My list of markers
                    for(int i=0; i<markers.size();i++) {
                        markers[i].setOnClickListener(clickListener);
                            //addContentView(markers[j].get(i), params);
                            relative.addView(markers[j].get(i), rParams);
                    }
                }
            }}}
```

Code when the location change (the markers move) :

```
public final static void moveSpot(Context c, View tv, GeoPoint p,
        float azimut, Location me, int screenWidth, float roll,
        int screenHeight, float pitch) {
    int angle = // Calculation for the position of the markers
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

            lp.leftMargin = -angle * screenWidth / 90;

    lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ABOVE);

    tv.setLayoutParams(lp);
}

public SensorEventListener createListener() {
    return new SensorEventListener() {
        public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor _sensor, int _accuracy) {

        }

        public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent evt) {
            if (evt.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION && markers != null) {

                for(int j=0;j<markers.length;j++)
                    moveSpot(context, markers[i], markers[i]
                                    .getGeoPoint(), azimut, myLoc,
                                    mScreenWidth, roll, mScreenHeight, pitch);

        }
    };
}
```

I think I don't take the right way so how can I do to prevent the overlapping of the markers ?
If you need precisions, ask and I'll try to be as precise as possible.

And sorry for my bad english :/

---

EDIT : Thanks to Martin Revert's response, I solved a part of my problem. Now I don't have problem of overlapping, but of position.

Here a screenshot of my application now :

http://hpics.li/f7c402b

On this picture, we can see there is no problem of overlapping anyway. 
That I would like to do is in this remake of the screenshot :

http://hpics.li/25a059d

I hope I'm clear this time :x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign an id to every View you create on your ViewGroup.

If every marker is a View use something like:

```
yourview[j].setId(j);
```

Do this before you apply your addRule() onto your "lp" layout.

EDIT:

You may also consider to take reference of every view position doing something like this:

```
lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ABOVE, yourview[j-1]);
```

Comment: Thanks, I did it and the result is much better but I would like that only overlapped views are displayed one on the other, because some markers pass over the screen :/

But it's a good progress, now the markers are not overlapped :)

Comment: Glad it helps, please accept and check the response as valid so others can reuse it in the future. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry I edited my answer, it helps but not resolved the problem :/

Comment: So you need to reformulate your problem. You wrote "The problem is that when markers are in the same direction, they are overlapped." and that problem is solved setting an id for every View and using the appropiate constants to position the Views (BELOW, ABOVE, etc.). So, why the response is not valid? Can you elaborate better your question please?

Comment: Added some info to my response.

Comment: I'll try to be more precise with an example:
I want to display 3 markers. Before, marker 1 was behind marker 2 and marker 3 was on the right of the screen.

At the beginning, I had in the top left of the screen, markers 1 and 2 overlapped and the marker 3 at the top right of the screen, with an horizontal distance between markers 1/2 and marker 3.

Now, with your solution, I have marker 1 at the top left, marker 2 just under marker 1 and marker 3 at the right but aligned under marker 2. 
I would like that if marker 3 isn't overlapped by another marker, it is displayed at the top of the screen.

Comment: If you use setId() and the correct parameters to position Views, no matter how many markers you create they will never be overlapped, maybe your're not setting also a rule to pùt them on TOP. If some marker is overlapping other you're not positioning well in the RelativeLayout. Remember also that you can add several addRule() methods per View to position all your Views. Be careful also with your margin settings, they can affect the rules.

Comment: I think you don't understand what I want to say, I have some difficulties to express myself in English.
I edit my first post with a screenshot of my application, and the description of the new problem.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm understanding the same as before: Your markers were behaving bad and overlapping in a "Z" axis dimension. I helped you to solve that problem with setId() method. Now you have to work your layout to position Views in correct "X" and "Y" axis dimensions, which is another problem that has nothing to do with overlapping. You must use public methods and verbs implemented in RelativeLayout.LayoutParams class to achieve what you need.

Comment: Ok I will work on it. I check the response as valid, thanks a lot !

Comment: Have the official doc as reference always, it helps me a lot to understand how to use Relative Layouts. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html. Also this tutorial is very clear http://blog.stylingandroid.com/archives/509, remeber that XML verbs have counterparts in Java, so it is same with a difference that android:id is replaced by setId(int), by example. Happy coding.

Comment: And this is a nice tutorial also http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-user-interface-design-relative-layouts/